# log rotation unable to process mailfirst

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, logrotate

I have configured log rotation on my Ubuntu server named `custom` in the directory `/etc/logrotation.d/custom` the entries are as follows

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log {
        daily
        mailfirst tarun@example.com
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
```

But when I run the command `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/custom` it gives the following error.

```
logrotate -f custom 
error: custom:3 unexpected text
```

It gives error in the line `mailfirst tarun@example.com`. Why? Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
var/log/apache2/access.log {
        daily
        mail tarun@example.com
        mailfirst 
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. One more thing I will have to install `mailutils` so that it can send mails?

Comment: mailutils install postfix, if that what you want, but will work.

Comment: Ok means I just need postfix and that will work for me?

Comment: No i said that installing mailutils will install postfix, some people might want sendmail or mutt, or whatever, you are fine installing mailutils.